# Why would adding a @Transactional annotation to Spring controller cause 404 errors

Tags: java, spring

I'm having a very odd problem. I've recently had to add a @Transactional annotation to one of our Spring controllers, and it suddenly is giving a 404 error when making any requests. No @Transactional, no errors. I've confirmed that the bean is being created in both instances, it just appears that Spring can't find the route. This is in Spring 5.3.27, not Spring Boot.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("business-objects")
@Transactional
public class BusinessObjectsController {
```

Since this is the only thing that has changed, I'm totally at a loss for why this would be happening, and am looking for any advice on what could be causing this issue.

Thanks!

Edit To Add:
So after digging into the bowels of Spring, looking in `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean`, when the annotation is added, it generates a JDK Proxy, which is then failing the `isHandler` check, so it's not being added to the mapping.

Comment: does it change anything if the route starts with / ? aka: "/business-objects" ?

Comment: Nope, no dice :(

Comment: show the stacktrace please

Comment: There is no stacktrace other than "No GET for business-objects" in the log when requests are made.

Comment: which @Transactional annotation are you using?

Comment: `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`